# Javascript Button User Permissions

Tags: managed-package, button

I am trying to put a Javascript button in a Managed Package, but I need to check the user permissions first. Is there a code equivalent to the Schema methods for Javascript? 
Something like the following code but that actually works

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/apex.js")} 
if(Schema.sObjectType.Dog__c.fields.Gender__c.isUpdateable()){ 
    var namespace_prefix = 'ERIDT1__'; 
}else{ 
    alert("Insufficient Access."); 
}
```

This code just gives me the error: Schema is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sforce.connection.describeSObject, which gives you an [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm), which includes the fields, and if they're createable and/or updateable. This describe result respects profile permissions.

Unfortunately, it's quite a bit of work, as you basically have to do this:

```
var result = sforce.connection.describeSObject('Dog__c');
var allowed = false;
result.fields.forEach(function(v) { if(v.name=='Gender__c' && v.updateable) allowed = true; });
if(!allowed) {
    alert("Insufficient access.");
} else {
    // Do what you will here
}
```

You could also use sforce.apex.execute, and call a class that returns the data you want.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I just had to change v.Name to v.name . Seemed to be case sensitive.

Comment: @Jennifer Yes, JS is case sensitive. I'll edit that for future visitors.